# Why I am getting null vales in @RequestBody Parameters?

Tags: rest, spring-mvc

I have created a simple REST service (POST). But when I call this service from postman @RequestBody is not receiving any values & getting nullPointer.

```
@RequestMapping(value=/searchEmployee,method = RequestMethod.POST,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<List<EmpDTO>> search(@RequestBody EmpSearchDTO empSearchDTO){
    String brId=empSearchDTO.getBrid();// null
    List<String> location=empSearchDTO.getLocation()//null
    Employee e=employeeRepository.findByEmployeeBrId(String brId);
    }
```

My java Bean object is like below:

```
public class EmpSearchDTO{

private String brId;
private List<String> location;

public void setBrid(String brId){
brId=brId;
}

public String getBrid(){
return brId;
}

public void setLocation(List<String location){
location=location;
}

public List<String> getLocation(){
return location;
}
}
```

JSON which I am passing in request body is

```
empSearchDTO
    {
       "brId":"G1234",
       "location":["India"]
    }
```

Comment: Can you share what you are using spring boot or non-spring boot configuration, as many dependencies are automatically taken care by spring boot. But if you are creating your own dependencies then you need to check if jackson dependencies are added to convert json to java object and vice versa

Comment: Thanks Amit for your response.
I am using Spring Boot.

Comment: Are you adding empSearchDTO in the json request?

Comment: can you please share your pom.xml also and are you adding "empSearchDTO" in the json request also? also check if spring-boot-starter-web dependency added in your pom.xml?